# Setting with enlargement - updating transaction DF

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns, insert-update

Looking for ways to achieve following updates on a dataframe:

- `dfb` is the base dataframe that I want to update with `dft` transactions.
- Any common index rows should be updated with values from `dft`.
- Indexes only in `dft` should be appended to `dfb`.

Looking at the documentation, setting with enlargement looked perfect but then I realized it only worked with a single row. Is it possible to use setting with enlargement to do this update or is there another method that could be recommended?

```
dfb = pd.DataFrame(data={'A': [11,22,33], 'B': [44,55,66]}, index=[1,2,3])
dfb
Out[70]: 
   A   B
1  11  44
2  22  55
3  33  66

dft = pd.DataFrame(data={'A': [0,2,3], 'B': [4,5,6]}, index=[3,4,5])
dft
Out[71]: 
   A  B
3  0  4
4  2  5
5  3  6

# Updated dfb should look like this:
dfb
Out[75]: 
    A   B
1  11  44
2  22  55
3   0   4
4   2   5
5   3   6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) with renaming columns, last convert `float` columns to `int` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html):

```
dft = dft.rename(columns={'c':'B', 'B':'A'}).combine_first(dfb).astype(int)
print (dft)
    A   B
1  11  44
2  22  55
3   0   4
4   2   5
5   3   6
```

Another solution with finding same indexes in both DataFrames by [`Index.intersection`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.intersection.html), [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) it from first `DataFrame` `dfb` and then use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
dft = dft.rename(columns={'c':'B', 'B':'A'})
idx = dfb.index.intersection(dft.index)
print (idx)
Int64Index([3], dtype='int64')

dfb = dfb.drop(idx)
print (dfb)
    A   B
1  11  44
2  22  55

print (pd.concat([dfb, dft]))
    A   B
1  11  44
2  22  55
3   0   4
4   2   5
5   3   6
```